# Shared questions between sites

Tags: feature-request

The answer is probably "no", but I ran into this question a [French speaker ultimately asking for a computer term](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134659/any-term-for-if-you-already-have-it-use-it-else-get-it-create-one) that was posted to English Language Learners, but it could have just as well been posted to Database Administrators (don't shoot me if I'm wrong about that). It would have been more useful, I believe, if the question would have been allowed to be "shared" between the two sites (such that members of both sites could have answered it).

Could we consider making that possible? Maybe not directly by the questioner, but maybe by a flag to "share to Database Administrators" that can appear in a Database Administrators queue to be accepted or rejected?

Or is this more trouble than it is worth?

Comment: Shouldn't that go to [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yeah @BDL it would make more sense.

Comment: There's already a related (maybe dup) MSE question: [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with “crossover questions” between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989/build-and-strengthen-the-stack-exchange-community-with-crossover-questions-bet)

Answer (score 2):

Different sites have different standards for how a question should be written, tagged, and otherwise presented. As such, questions need to be *tailored* for the particular site that they are being asked on, and part of this tailoring process is deciding which group of experts you want to answer your question—database experts? English language experts? programmers? linguists? Simply mirroring the question on multiple sites would prevent users from being able to adapt their questions to the site they want to ask on, which is an important step in asking a good question.

Furthermore, different sites have different standards for what is and what is not on-topic. I suspect that English word requests are *not* on-topic for Database Administrators, even though the words are vaguely related to databases. Certainly, this question (and questions like it) would *not* be on-topic for Stack Overflow. Which suggests another problem with this approach: you wanted to "share" this question with the Database Administrators site *without knowing if the question is even on-topic there*! It's not hard to imagine how that could go wrong. This is the same reason why migration paths are heavily restricted: because users of one site don't necessarily know what is suitable for *other* sites on the network.

You also need to consider the logistical problems. (And no, I don't just mean the difficulty of implementing it, but that *is* a consideration.) What I mean is, for example, which site *owns* the question? That matters because it determines who gets to *edit* the question, whose standards/guidelines apply, whose tags get used, what happens if it gets closed (or who has the privileges to close it), etc. etc.